# how to get the data using XPATH from div with display:none?

Tags: xpath

I want to extract data from a `div` element with the attribute 'display:none'.

```
<div class='test' style='display:none;'>
  <div id='test2'>data</div>
</div>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
//div[@class = "test"]//div[contains(@style, \'display:none\')';
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try several changes:

1) Just put normal quotes around "display:none", like you did for your `class` attribute and close with `]`

2) Then your `div` with `class` test and your style attribute is one and the same, so you need to call `contains` also for the same `div`:

```
'//div[@class = "test" and contains(@style, "display:none")]'
```

or the quotes the other way around, important is, that you are using differnt quotes around the expression than inside the expression

```
"//div[@class = 'test' and contains(@style, 'display:none')]"
```

if this still does not work, pls post an error message

Comment: i wrote: '//div[class = "test" and contains(@style, 'display:none')]', but result = empty line.

Comment: @Chingismtm -> yeah as I said, you need to have different quotes inside your expression than for the expression itself -> so because you are using ' around the expression you need to use " inside the expression -> will update my answer a bit